# Settings test data attributes as anchors in react application in testing environment

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, nightwatch.js

I am using the [nightwatch](https://nightwatchjs.org/) for end-to-end testing my application. At the same time I use CSS modules within build, what does not allow me to link css-selectors to some constants in the test code:

```
module.exports = {
    url() {
        return this.api.launchUrl`;
    },
    elements: {
        reactComponent: {
            selector: '?',
        },
    },
};
```

Is there a convenient way/approach to assign some sort of `test-id=*` attributes to the react components automatically in the react project (depending on environment mode) or should I do this work explicitly?

Comment: From my experience... You need to add the ids explicitly to the components. This is also a good practice to ensure you know exactly what id you are testing and not just having another layer your tests could break (knowing the id was not there because of that global adding logic or an actual error in the app). You can pass values down though. So you can have a 'cascading' testing ids where as it moves down you pass it along and the children components just add on.

Comment: Actually, if the person who is developing the React page follows React's guidelines then there won't be any React elements with id's because that is supposed to be taboo since React uses recycled views and id's are specific for one view/element.  I'm not exactly sure why you cannot enter the CSS properties for the element selector since CSS is a valid locator strategy.  Try using an already available data attribute in the form of '[data-attribute="whatever"]'.  That's what I use for our React apps and it works fine.  Anything but xpath haha

Comment: @king_wayne the problem is that there are no data attributes, and I am looking for a way to set it up (automatically or manually).

Comment: I want to it to be fully deterministic and I do not want to have excessive data attributes in production mode.

Comment: I have a way of determining values based on environments if that helps you.  I pass in an `--env` argument from the command line then access it in my script using `process.argv[3]` then depending on that value I go to a data file (json) and retrieve the values that way.  Not sure how this will help with an element's selector, but maybe that will help give you an idea?

Comment: @king_wayne I think I'll just add these test ids and strip them in the production build.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you will have to set the `test-id` attributes yourself.

We are in a similar situation with a React project where we don't want our test attributes to be visible in production all the time. To solve this, each of our test attributes is set up like

```
test-id=${testIdFunc('someComponentName')}
```

Then, we have a block of code in our React Root component that checks for the existence of a certain cookie in the browser. If the cookie is present, then `testIdFunc` is defined to be `id => id`, and if the cookie is not present, then it's defined to be `() => null`. `testIdFunc` is then set on the React Context so that any component can access it.

The final result is that you only get your test attributes showing up if that cookie is present, which sounds like what you want.

To access this in your tests, as soon as you open a browser window, you need to navigate to some URL on your domain (preferably one that loads quickly), set the test cookie, and refresh the page (or navigate to whatever URL you want to start testing on).

Comment: I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-jsx-remove-data-test-id) package gives a similar result

Comment: Similar, yes, except that it doesn't let you turn on the `data-test-id`s in prod, so you can't run your tests in prod.